# How to link app against a library that depends on another library?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I wrote a shared library `mylib1` that uses a 3rd-party shared library, in my case `libtinyxml2` (for this problem the 3rd-party library is irrelevant: it can be any library). And I wrote an application `app1` which depends on `mylib1`.

Building `mylib1` succeeds, but building `app1` fails, presumably because the linker was not told to link against `libtinyxml2` when linking `app1`.

What am I missing?

```
[I][~/Programs/cmake-jenkins/big_proj/src/build]$ make
[ 25%] Building CXX object mylib1/CMakeFiles/mylib1.dir/src/my_functions.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib1.so
[ 50%] Built target mylib1
[ 75%] Building CXX object app1/CMakeFiles/app1.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable app1
../mylib1/libmylib1.so: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::StrPair::Reset()'
../mylib1/libmylib1.so: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::StrPair::~StrPair()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [app1/CMakeFiles/app1.dir/build.make:97: app1/app1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:402: app1/CMakeFiles/app1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

## Folder structure

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── functions_p.hpp
│   │   └── main.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── mylib1
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── src
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── my_functions.hpp
    │   └── my_functions.cpp
```

---

### ./CMakeLists.txt

```
# Top level CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.2)

add_subdirectory(app1)
add_subdirectory(mylib1)
```

## app1/CMakeLists.txt

```
project("app1" CXX)

set(APP1_SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp )
add_executable(app1 ${APP1_SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(app1
    PRIVATE src/include)
target_link_libraries(app1 mylib1)
```

---

## mylib1/CMakeLists.txt

```
project("lib1" CXX)

find_library(TINYXML_LIB tinyxml2 REQUIRED)

set(MYLIB1_SOURCE_FILES src/my_functions.cpp )
set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_FILES src/include/my_functions.hpp)
add_library(mylib1 SHARED ${MYLIB1_SOURCE_FILES} ${MYLIB1_INCLUDE_FILES} )

target_include_directories(mylib1
    PUBLIC src/include)
# I have checked that TINYXML_LIB is set, so the library IS found.
target_link_libraries(mylib1 PUBLIC ${TINYXML_LIB})
```

---

The `readelf` output shows the library has a dependency to `libtinyxml2.so.6`, and this file exists as `/usr/lib/libtinyxml2.so.6` on my system.

```
[I][~/Programs/cmake-jenkins/big_proj/src/build]$ readelf -d mylib1/libmylib1.so
Dynamic section at offset 0x16cd0 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libtinyxml2.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libmylib1.so]
```

Running the generated `Makefile` in verbose mode shows that indeed when `app1` is linked, it does not link against `libtinyxml2`:

```
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable app1
cd /home/danb/Programs/cmake-jenkins/big_proj/src/build/app1 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/app1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/app1.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o app1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/danb/Programs/cmake-jenkins/big_proj/src/build/mylib1 ../mylib1/libmylib1.so
```

Comment: Which link command is used to create your executable? You may see it with `make VERBOSE=1`. Also, `/usr/include/libtinyxml2.so.6` seems to be a typo - libraries are normally located under `/usr/lib` or so.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're right, it's a typo, thanks. I pasted the verbose link command at the end of my question.

Comment: It is not a CMake responsibility to link with `libtinyxml2`, so this library is absent in the command line. It is linker who should detect `DT_NEEDED` things and process them accordingly. But for some reason it doesn't do that. Some description about "secondary linking" may be found in this blogpost: http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the input. I have read that article before posting this question, and did not find my answer. I will try linking manually without CMake/make, it might give a clue what's going wrong.

Comment: Could you display `message(STATUS "${TINYXML_LIB}")` ? Since it is in `PUBLIC` it should fill the target `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`
Also can you use find_package() instead of find_library instead to get a target 'object' with include directory etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the tinyxml2 library or my installation of it (but it's from the official ArchLinux repository), because I've replaced it with 2 other libraries, and there were no issues building `app1`.

I even tried to link `app1` manually and it would still give the same `undefined reference` errors:

```
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/app1.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o app1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/danb/Programs/cmake-jenkins/big_proj/src/build/mylib1 ../mylib1/libmylib1.so -ltinyxml2 -L /usr/lib
```

I also tried using `find_package()` instead of `find_library()`, because libtinyxml2 comes with a CMake module, but the problem remained.

What's funny is that I don't even make use of `tinyxml2::StrPair::Reset()`. This is all that the library implements:

```
#include <tinyxml2.h>

bool is_xml_empty() {
    tinyxml2::StrPair pair;
    char* a;
    char* b;
    pair.Set(a, b, 0);
    return pair.Empty();
}
```

And yet! I can build a software ([encfs](https://github.com/vgough/encfs)) that depends on `tinyxml2`, and it builds just fine! This indicates my installation of the library is fine.

Answer (score 1):

External references are resolved when the final application is linked so include libtinyxml2 in `target_link_libraries` in `app1/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: But the build system should take care of the dependency tree. If in target `mylib1` I define all its dependencies, I surely shouldn't have to define all dependencies of `mylib1` again in every target that depends on `mylib1`.

Answer (score 1):

CMake implements this feature in the modules. See [CMake Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-modules.7.html)
If necessary modules create a variable `FOOMODULE_LIBRARIES`. This variable is a list of

> The libraries needed to use ...

Thus you can add this dependency by:

1. Providing a module script for mylib1
2. Use find_package(mylib1) in project app1

Example:

```
find_package (mylib1)
include_directories(${mylib1_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(app1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app1 ${mylib1_LIBRARIES})
```

Note: This makes `mylib1` independent from `app1`. You have to do extra work to trigger a build of `app1` for any change of `mylib1`. See [CMake Tutorials at http://www.th-thielemann.de/development](http://www.th-thielemann.de/development/)